# TypeScript return type of typeof should be string?

Tags: typescript, typeof

```
type typeof_returntype = ReturnType<typeof typeof> // should be string?
```

I was just playing around when I noticed that [I can't get](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBKkPYDMD6AnCwCuKB2toF4oAldLbAFXAgB49EYrEA+AKBaA) the return type of the function `typeof`. Is this by design?

Comment: `typeof` is not a function; what makes you think it is one?

Comment: I mean, you can *make* a function that wraps the `typeof` operator like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvVl3W), is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Or do you want a generic type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR5gYW)?

Comment: @jcalz that one can write `typeof(4)`, but I see my mistake now, what you wrote is what I was thinking of

Comment: Ah, sure. Yeah, it's an operator and not a function.  So, do you want to see an answer here?  After all you *can* get the union of string literal results of `typeof` as a type if you wrap the operator in a function.

Comment: @jcalz I would be willing to accept the answer for sure. I guess this will be useful as a  reminder that `typeof` is an operator and not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` is an operator not a function, therefore one cannot extract its return type. But one can get "the union of string literal results of `typeof` as a type if you wrap the operator in a function".

```
const typeOf = (x: any) => typeof x;
type typeof_returntype = ReturnType<typeof typeOf>;
// "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

---

[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260735/typescript-return-type-of-typeof-should-be-string/71271874#comment125981171_71260735) by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz)